# Normalized eigenvectors are different depending on when the limit is calculated

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra

I have this code:

```
x[t_] = Simplify[ Normal[Series[Sqrt[\[Omega]^2*(1 + \[Epsilon]*Sin[\[CapitalOmega]*t] + 
    a*Sin[\[CapitalOmega]*t])], {a, 0, 1}, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]], Assumptions -> {\[Omega] > 0}]

y = (1/T)*Integrate[x[t], {t, 0, T}]
\[Delta]\[Omega][t_] = x[t] - y

A = Series[{{Exp[-I*y*T], 
  Normal[Integrate[
    Series[(D[x[t], t]/(2*x[t]))*
      Exp[2 I*Integrate[\[Delta]\[Omega][\[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, 
          T}]]*Exp[I*y*t], {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}], {t, 0, 
     T}]]}, {Normal[
   Integrate[
    Series[(D[x[t], t]/(2*x[t]))*
      Exp[-2 I*
        Integrate[\[Delta]\[Omega][\[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, T}]]*
      Exp[-I*y*t], {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}], {t, 0, T}]], 
  Exp[I*y*T]}}, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}]/. \[Omega] -> 1 /. \[CapitalOmega] -> 5 /. T -> 4 // Normal;
```

After Mathematica finishes running (it takes around $1$ minute), I can calculate the eigenvectors of my matrix $A$ with

```
 Normalize[Eigenvectors[A][[1]]] /. a -> 0.00000001 /. \[Epsilon] ->0.00000001
 Normalize[Eigenvectors[A][[2]]] /. a -> 0.00000001 /. \[Epsilon] -> 0.00000001
```

to find that my eigenvectors are:

```
{0.870066 - 0.492935 I, 3.73447*10^-9}

{-7.23137*10^-8 + 3.70733*10^-8 I, 1.}
```

If instead I set the values of $\epsilon$ and $a$ first,

```
Eigenvectors[A /.a -> 0.00000001 /. \[Epsilon] -> 0.00000001]
```

I find

```
{{3.24924*10^-9 - 1.84085*10^-9 I, 1. + 0. I}, 
{1. + 0. I, 3.24924*10^-9 + 1.84085*10^-9 I}}
```

which makes sense as

\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+\\a\to0^+}A\to\begin{pmatrix}e^{-iyT} & 0\\
0 & e^{iyT} \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

and every diagonal matrix has eigenvectors of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. However, I'm not sure why Mathematica gives me two different sets of eigenvectors, depending on when I take $\epsilon$ and $a$ to $0$. I am especially concerned about getting $(0.870066 - 0.492935i,0)$ vs $(1,0)$. Both are valid eigenvectors, but I don't understand why Mathematica doesn't factor out $0.870066 - 0.492935i$ and output $(1,0)$ in both cases.

Comment: When an eigenvector has multiplicity greate that 1, the "set of eigenvectors" is not uniquely determined. You problem might be related to this.

Comment: Shouldn't I get two distinct eigenvectors? I know that the eigenvalues are distinct

Comment: Eigenvalues do not have to be distinct

Comment: Simply put, Mathematica uses different algorithms when calculating symbolic and numeric matrices. In your first approach, Mathematica uses a symbolic algorithm, and gives general expressions for eigenvectors. Note that these will always be linearly independend, but they are not guaranteed to be orthogonal, and they are also generally not normalized. This normalization is what you are missing in (0.870066−0.492935,0).

Comment: Of course, when they belong to distinct eigenvalues, they will be orthogonal as well, but again, may not be normalized. Under "Details and Options" in the documentation for "Eigenvectors" : "For exact or symbolic matrices m, the eigenvectors are not normalized."

Comment: Most definitely the symbolic eigenvectors are not normalized. But it is not clear to me that they need to be orthogonal. Is the matrix symmetric?